# Add Prefix Tags to JSON Passed to a WCF Service in c#

Tags: c#, json, wcf

We are passing JSON request to a WCF service which comprises some additional prefixes like xy1, xy2 and “@” sign etc which makes it customized JSON. Our WCF service’s create order method process this customized JSON to create orders.
We want to pass standard JSON to WCF service instead of customized one. Is there any way to pass standard JSON to WCF service and then it converts back to customized JSON with minimum code changes.

NOTE: This is sample JSON but actual JSON file is long and comprises more details.

customized JSON is as following:

```
{
    "xy1:createOrder": {
        "@test:xy1": "http://www.testing.com/schema/order",
        "@test:xy2": "http://www.testing.com/schema/customer",
        "xy1:order": {
            "@Date": "2022-12-27",
            "@orderNo": "FirstOrder1"
        },
        "xy2:customer": {
            "@Id": "1",
            "xy2:title": "Mr",
            "xy2:fName": "Alex",
            "xy2:lName": "John",
            "xy2:emailId": "aj@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

standard JSON is as following:

```
{
    "createOrder": {
        "order": {
            "Date": "2022-12-27",
            "orderNo": "FirstOrder1"
        },
        "customer": {
            "Id": "1",
            "title": "Mr",
            "fName": "Alex",
            "lName": "John",
            "emailId": "aj@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a free coder service , you have to show us what you have tried so far and what is the problem.

Comment: We want to pass cleaned JSON object to WCF service and then attach prefixed in it so that it can be processed by our create order method.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
    var origJObj = JObject.Parse(json).Dump();
    var cleanedJObj = new JObject();
    
    CleanJsonObject(origJObj, cleanedJObj);

    //if you need a json
    json = cleanedJObj.ToString();


public void CleanJsonObject(JObject origJObj, JObject cleanedJObj)
{
    foreach (var prop in origJObj.Properties())
    {
        var name = "";
        var startIndex = prop.Name.IndexOf(":");
        if (startIndex > 0)
        {
            name = prop.Name.Substring(startIndex + 1);
        }
        else name = prop.Name.Replace("@", "");
        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            var newJObj = new JObject();
            CleanJsonObject((JObject)prop.Value, newJObj);
            cleanedJObj.Add(name, newJObj);
        }
        else
        {
            cleanedJObj.Add(name, prop.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to eliminating unnecessary parts of your code, try [josn.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to customize your requirements.

An example of how to use it:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
        name = (string) jUser["name"];
        teamname = (string) jUser["teamname"];
        email = (string) jUser["email"];
        players = jUser["players"].ToArray();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}

// Use
private void Run()
{
    string json = @"{""user"":{""name"":""asdf"",""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";
    User user = new User(json);

    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
    Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
    Console.WriteLine("Players:");

    foreach (var player in user.players)
        Console.WriteLine(player);
 }
```

Comment: We want to pass standard JSON to WCF service and then convert it back to customized one. The JSON which does not contain any prefixes is mentioned as standard and the JSON which contains prefixes is marked as customized one.

Comment: Why would you want to do this when you can just transfer the data in a custom Json format.

Comment: We want to do this so that we can achieve re-usability of our existing logic to process it.